# Is there any documented evidence that these three North American cities were named due to the locations of their namesakes?

Tags: europe, names, north-america, maps, cities

Two years ago, I was studying an online atlas of the world and I happened to notice that there are three cities located in North America which have a geographical similarity with three cities located in Europe.

The three cities in North America are London, Ontario, Port Dover, Ontario, and Dunkirk, New York. The three cities in Europe are London, England, Dover, England, and Dunkirk, France.

If you study the two maps shown below, you will notice the geographical similarities between these six cities.

[image]
London, Ontario, Port Dover, Ontario, and Dunkirk, New York.

[image]
London, England, Dover, England, and Dunkirk, France.

I think it is also interesting that according to Google Maps, the flying distance from London, Ontario to Dunkirk, New York is approximately 103 miles and the flying distance from London, England to Dunkirk, France is approximately 109 miles.

I am very curious to find out if someone else, perhaps a historian or a map maker, had also noticed the geographical similarities of these six cities and if he/she had written an article about it. I am hoping that if there is such an article, that this article will have an explanation as to why these North American cities had been named after those cities in Europe.

I have spent many hours searching the Internet over the past two years for such an article, but I have not found it yet. I am hoping that someone on History.SE will be able to answer this for me.

Has anyone ever written about the geographical similarities of these three cities in North America with three cities in Europe?

Comment: This would only be interesting if there were any source, or even reason to believe, that this is intentional, and not just a coincidence. Perhaps supported by cities in those regions settled / named by people from Britain / France.

Comment: It's known that cities in North America cluster along [fall lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_line) but I don't know if something similar could be going on here.

Comment: If I recall, [WIlliam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) wrote something about it in the 14th century and [Klaus Conrad in 1958](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia) </humor>

Comment: I've a strong feeling of deja vu, I'm sure there's been a question about these locations posted here before.

Comment: @KillingTime Yes, I too recall this being asked and was soon deleted due to the downvotes.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is considered to be in the realm of social sciences. I think why people in the past named their cities they way they did should be considered to be in the realm of history. For example, if I were to have asked the question, "Why did the French people name their largest city 'Paris'?", this question would be considered by most people to be a history-related question and one that most likely has an answer.

Comment: IMHO if there's an historical reason for this (and it seems quite possible), this is perfectly on-topic.

Comment: First run of the [same question 2 years ago](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/64414/16951).

Comment: It's possible Port Dover may have been named due to the location of London further inland. Dover Mills (later Port Dover)  was named a year after London was. Dunkirk most likely is a coincidence. It was named by the French and I doubt the French would take a cue from the British in naming one of their towns. It's a neat coincidence though.

Comment: @DevSolar Whether it was intentional or not is what the question is asking. Is there evidence for one or more of these cities being named due to the physical distances of the originals?

Comment: Quick review (preliminary research) of the history page for each city suggests [London Ontario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London,_Ontario) 1793, [Port Dover](https://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/port-dover) 1804 and [Dunkirk, New York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunkirk,_New_York) 1826  were probably not partners in a vast international conspiracy to govern the naming of cities in the new world. They were named after European cities, because the settlers came from Europe.  Conspiracy is always less probable than coincidence.

Comment: @MCW That was basicly the conclusion that the original author ([2021-07-08: Is it just a coincidence that the locations of three cities in North America share a unique geographical similarity to three cities in Europe?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/64414/is-it-just-a-coincidence-that-the-locations-of-three-cities-in-north-america-sha)) in the end came to. That would, togeather with the research, would have been a **valid answer**. But since the question was downvoted and closed couldn't, so the OP deleted it instead. The downvotes and closure was then the wrong approach.

Comment: It is also unlikely that the required maps of both areas were available during the timeframe of 1793-1826. So the peaple then were probably unaware of this quirke coincidence that had developed.